# mediawiki application not working properly in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on MediaWiki which is in php . For some reason i have to open all this application in an iframe . Everything is working except the **Edit link for pages**. I am using this like .

In this snippet one link is working properly But link 2 is not working **i mean it is blank page** . Don't know where is problem . Any help will be appreciated

```html
<iframe width="100%" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/manoj"></iframe>
<iframe width="100%" src="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IFrame&action=edit&editintro=Template:Disambig_editintro"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved the issue . Just need to set `X-frame` in default setting in the `include/defaultsetting.php` . set `$wgEditPageFrameOptions = 'deny';` to `$wgEditPageFrameOptions = false;`. and all is working fine now.

Comment: nice @ShowStopper it's run